# Trying to attach clothes to mixamo animated character, and I am getting some weird deformations. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

My apologies for not having gif show on my post, Im having some server issues uploading the gif here. The gif of my issue can be seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/joKoiwP) and blend file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_rcMMGntcpd3T3KcHctlqLJGdbk-f4s/view?usp=drive_link).

Im using mixamo to animate my character, and am trying to put a sweater on the animated character in blender.

Following advice from a recent post here, I made sure to align the sweater with my characters rest position, then have the animation start about 20 frames in. Then I used a data transfer to transfer vertex group and weight information from my mixamo animated body to the sweater, so the sweater should deform properly with the body. However, as can be seen in the video, the sweater is not deforming properly with the animation. What am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated, thanks!